# node js server is not working on shared hosting server

Tags: node.js

I am working on a Node.js app.

Hosting of node js for my app is not working so I just create one small sample demo for hosting node js on server but still its not working.

I share you the code and step that I have done until now for setup the code.

`ServerDemo.js`

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(12043, '0.0.0.0');
console.log('Server running at : http://0.0.0.0:12043/');
```

then I have connect my server from PuTTy and then I run my `serverdemo.js` with following command

```
nodejs /var/www/websites/webrtc.windinternet.nl/htdocs/webrtcapp/serverdemo.js
```

it will so the following output

```
Server running at : http://0.0.0.0:12043/
```

then I enter

```
$ netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
```

which so following output

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:12043           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::4949                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

so port 12043 is listening but when I'm running `$ nmap -sT localhost` command it shows only following ports are open:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

when I am trying to access `http://test.domain.com:12043` it always display `The webpage is not available`.

If you need any more description from my side, please add comments.

Comment: Did you check whether there are any firewall rules blocking the port? Run `iptables -nvL` to see all the rules, those of the `OUTPUT` and `INPUT` chain are interesting in this case.

Comment: Also, you might try to open a connection from your computer using telnet: `telnet test.domain.com 12043`.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that `nmap -sT` by default will _not_ check port 12043, unless you explicitly instruct it to do so.

Comment: thank you very much for your help guys when i run telnet test.domain.com 12043 it displaying Trying 127.0.1.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused then iptables -nvL is displaying access denied is it necessary that i am login with root for that??for running node js server is it necessary to start my port 12043 before i create node server on 12043??

Comment: Wait, are you running the telnet command from the server or from your local computer? Try it from your local computer. If that’s what you’re already doing, does test.domain.com have it's DNS record st to 127.0.1.1? Then that must be the problem.

Comment: @cdauth yes i am running putty.exe from local and access the shared server from putty console. i run the following command $ telnet test.domain.com 12043 is this right?? here i have to share one thing to u i am not the root user of the server so may be i have not access for run telnet command is it possible that it may be a reason??

Comment: It’s a big mystery to me. If iptables was blocking the request, you wouldn’t get a “Connection refused”. But netstat clearly shows that something is listening on that port.

Comment: you are like my rock-star brother god bless u a lot...after entering following command it works telnet -l username test.domain.com 12043

Answer (score 1):

While you host Node.js application on shared server as per my question you have to run follow above steps as i mention and at last you need to open respected port on server for running node.js application.

Command : telnet -l username test.domain.com 12043

This telnet command open the respected port and Your application is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will work. Try it once...

Give your machine an IP address or `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0`.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(12043, 'localhost');

console.log('Server running at : http://localhost:12043/');
```